# Выход за предел массива

Tags: массивы, pascal

```
function IntToArr(a: integer): array of integer; //функция перевода числа в массив цифр
begin
    a := Abs(a);
    var i: integer := 1;
    SetLength(Result, i);
    while a >= 10 do //считывание цифр по разрядам от меньшего (до предпоследнего)
    begin
        Result[i - 1] := a mod 10; //цифра в текущем разряде
        a := a div 10; //перевод в следующий разряд
        i += 1;
        SetLength(Result, i); //увеличение длины массива
    end;
    Result[i - 1] := a; //цифра наивысшего разряда
    Reverse(Result); //упорядочивание по порядку числа
end;

function IntDiv(a: integer): integer; //функция для подсчёта разрядов в числе
begin
    Result := 0;
    while a <> 0 do
    begin
        a := a div 10;
        Result += 1;
    end;
end;

var
    a, b, i, nmax, nmin: integer;
    num: array of integer;

begin //программа для нахождения наименьшей и наибольшей цифры в числе
    Readln(a);
    num := IntToArr(a);
    writeln(num);
    b := IntDiv(a); //разбираем на массив
    writeln('Кол-во разрядов: ', b);
    nmin := num[1]; //устанавливаем первый элемент
    for i := 1 to b do
    begin
        if num[i] < nmin then nmin := num[i]; //нахождение наименьшего значения (ошибка выхода за пределы массива)
    end;
    writeln('Наименьшая цифра: ', nmin);
    nmax := num[1]; //устанавливаем первый элемент
    for i := 1 to b do
    begin
        if num[i] > nmax then nmin := num[i]; //нахождение наибольшего значения (ошибка выхода за пределы массива)
    end;
    writeln('Наибольшая цифра: ', nmax);
end.
```

Не могу понять в чём дело - программа компилится, при выборе наименьшего и наибольшего элемента динамического массива происходит выход за пределы массива, хотя по идее не должен. Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

Comment: начальные min/max делайте по `num[0]`, а цикл уже сделайте от 1 до b-1, у вас `IntToArr` такой массив возвращает (т.е. с индексами 0..n-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[В справке](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Structured_Types#Dynamic_Arrays) вы можете увидеть уточнение

> Once a dynamic array has been allocated, you can pass it to the standard functions Length, High, and Low. Length returns the number of elements in the array, High returns the array's highest index (that is, Length - 1), and Low returns 0. In the case of a zero-length array, High returns -1 (with the anomalous consequence that High < Low).
>
> ---
>
> После того, как динамический массив был выделен, вы можете передавать его в стандартные функции *Length*, *High*, *Low*. *Length* возвращает количество элементов в массиве, *High* возвращает максимальный индекс массива (то есть, Length - 1), и *Low* - 0. В случае массива нулевой длины, *High* вернет -1 (с аномальным следствием, что максимальный индекс меньше минимального).

Таким образом можно исправить цикл и уйти от жестких констант

```
nmin := num[Low(num)]; //устанавливаем первый элемент
```

и цикл

```
for i := Low(num) to High(num) do
```

Так же из справки видно, что динамические массивы имеют индексы от `0` до `Length-1`.
В то время как вы пытаетесь обращаться к ним с `1` до `b` - который равен *Length*. Так что еще одним вариантом может стать смещение индекса на 1

```
nmax := num[0];
```

а так же либо внутри цикла

```
if num[i-1] < nmin then nmin := num[i-1];
```

либо в определении цикла

```
for i := 0 to b-1 do
```